# wxpython compilation

Tags: wxpython

I'm trying wxpython for the first time,so i need a sample program with the details of how to run it

Answer (score 2):

There are several tutorials available. You might want to start here: http://wiki.wxpython.org/Getting%20Started

Among other things, this page includes some sample applications, from a simple "Hello World" to event-handling and other examples.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a several useful tutorials for beginner. It was very helpful to me. You can learn beginner to intermediate level.

http://zetcode.com/wxpython/

Answer (score -1):

First make sure you have python 2.7.x installed on your system then head to the [wxpython download](http://www.wxpython.org/download.php) page and download the relevant binaries for your system as well as the docs and demos.If you are using linux get wxpython from your distributions repository.
copy and save the following script as app.py

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import wx

#implimenting a the frame
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    #Begining __init__()
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent = None, id = -1, title = "A simple App", pos = (-1, -1), size = (400, 300), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE)
    #End __init__()

#implimenting the application
class MyApp(wx.App):
    #Begining OnInit(self)
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = MyFrame()
        self.frame.Show(True)
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
        return True
    #End OnInit(self)

#first chech whether the script is being run as the main script if so run the main application loop
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MyApp()
    app.MainLoop()
```

On windows just double click the script to run it on unix systems first launch the terminal and change the working directory to the one where you've saved the script, then execute `chmod +x app.py` then `./app.py` to run it.
You should also look into the book "wxpython in action 2012".